# Configure latexmk to recognize an old file with a new name

Tags: latexmk, asymptote

When the `asymptote` package is used, it generates Asymptote source files with sequential names. For instance, if the `tex` file is called `foo.tex`, then running LaTeX on it will generate Asymptote source files `foo-1.asy`, `foo-2.asy`, `foo-3.asy`, etc. If `latexmk` is used with the configuration file [asymptote_latexmkrc](http://ctan.mackichan.com/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/asymptote_latexmkrc), then it automatically recognizes when a file has not changed and compiles only the ones that have changed--which is a huge timesaver.

Unfortunately, if an Asymptote image is added or removed early in the document, then it changes the filenames of all the subsequent images. This makes `latexmk` think that these all need to be recompiled, which is time-consuming and a real pain.

Can `latexmk` be configured to recognize an old file with a new name, and simply change the name of the compiled image to match without recompiling it? I imagine that this would involve having `latexmk` maintain a database of the contents of the `.asy` source files from the last run.

Comment: Guess: `\begin{asy}
include "asy-figure";
\end{asy}` <-- does this work or may be generate standalone asymptote figures like tikzexternalize.

Comment: @texenthusiast: If I wanted to have all my asymptote code given in separate files, I could use the method you suggest or the command `\asyinclude`, which is designed to work with `latexmk`. The point of this question is that I want to give the code in the actual tex file, and ideally not have to name all of the figures (I have over 120 so far, and many of them are quite trivial).

Comment: The `.asy` files contain their base names (e.g., `foo-2`).  So if one of the images is removed, not only do the names of later `.asy` files also change, but also their contents.  The `.tex` and `.pre` files produced by the `asy` program also contain changed file names.  So there's no realistic alternative to rerunning the `asy` program, which is what `latexmk` does.  IMHO, it would be useful to request an update to the `asymptote` package so that the base string for the produced files can be specified by the user as an optional argument to the `asy` environment.

Comment: @John Collins: I am grateful for your explanation. I'm pretty sure that the line `defaultfilename="foo-2";` could be eliminated with no ill effects. If this were done, would a solution become feasible?

Comment: The output files still contain names of generated files.  Removing the `defaultfilename` line simply changes the name of the generated files.